Language that records and enforces type constraints/predicates
I'm working on an experimental JVM-based programming language and would like record and verify additional type constraints (beyond the types themselves).
In Kotlin and many other modern programming languages you can write
fun exp(base: Number, exponent: Int): Number
{
  return if (base is BigDecimal)
  {
    base.pow(exponent)
  }
  else 0
}

Even though base is declared as Number the compiler allows invoking the pow method, because at that location it is known that base is actually a BigDecimal. This is one of a few special cases where the compiler detects a particular situation and generates some extra code under the hood to make it work.
I would like to create a similar mechanism, but in a much more generic fashion, and I'd like to extend it from pure type information to also include additional predicates.
For example, division is only allowed when the divisor is non-zero, so I'd like to be able to extend this concept for cases like this:
if (divisor != 0)
{
    dividend/divisor
}

The compiler should reject the division if it is not in a context where the divisor is known to be non-zero.
Notably, I would prefer as little as possible of the mechanism to be hard-coded into the compiler.
There is an existing syntax for expressing such type constraints:
Real dividedBy[/](Real divisor:: != 0)

The method declaration indicates that the division can only be performed for non-zero divisors and should be flagged by the compiler otherwise.
Currently, the additional constraints are recorded as type annotations that are suitable for consumption by an SMT simplifier/solver (supporting a limited number of boolean and numeric operations).
However, I'm still struggling with collecting constraints in nested scenarios, and there are probably plenty of tricky scenarios that I don't even know about.
Are there existing languages that support such a mechanism that I could use as a template or guideline? Are there well-known implementation approaches for such a feature?

I think these two previous questions are relevant here but likely not duplicates: How the compiler or runtime handles types which are complex patterns or have complex constraints?, What language was the first to treat null checks as smart casts to non-nullable types?

Rust has a NonZero type, but it's implemented in the library, not in the compiler, so it's not relevant here.

@EldritchConundrum Thanks, I'll still have a look at that Rust NonZero type. Ideally, I only want the compiler to provide the high-level mechanism, but specific constraints should be implementable in a library, etc. So, Rust's NonZero may not be all that far off.

As an aside, do you have more examples of constraints, appart from numerical constraints, subtyping contraints, and null?

@PabloH You've pretty much summarized the main use cases in my mind. Size constraints on matrix and tensor types are another use that I'm interested in, but I guess that falls into the "numeric" category as well. Any boolean-valued function can be used in constraints, e.g., indicating whether the object has undergone a certain type of processing already. I see this feature mainly as a remedy for situations where purely type-based solutions run into problems with LSP or are otherwise unpractical (e.g., Integer and NonZeroInteger types), or where an existing API imposes sequential coupling.

For dynamic checks, it's called flow-sensitive typing. Check out type narrowing in TypeScript. More common in statically typed languages is refinement types. Every type can be refined with additional predicates, like your non-zero example. Check out LiquidHaskell.

I think Shen might be interesting to know in this context, AFAIK the type system is using Prolog so its both powerful and undecidable

C++ has if constexpr (divisor != 0) - not a special case at all. C++ compilers implement a fairly large subset of C++ at compile time. Also, C++ has first-class language support for concepts.

This looks like liquid types (short for "logically qualified data types"), or more generally, refinement types.
Liquid Haskell and F* support refinement types.
For example in F* you can write programs with statically-checked invariants like:
let rec sorted_concat (#a:eqtype)
  (f:total_order_t a)
  (l1:list a{sorted f l1})
  (l2:list a{sorted f l2})
  (pivot:a)
  : Lemma (requires (forall y. mem y l1 ==> not (f pivot y)) /\
  (forall y. mem y l2 ==> f pivot y))
  (ensures sorted f (append l1 (pivot :: l2)))


There is also Flux: liquid types for Rust.
